# Rails 3.2 has_many :as polymorphic, Simple Form, simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-many, cocoon-gem

Trying to save some images in my product form. I'm excpecting paremeters where I would have images_attributes being a part of "product". When I make parameters like that in the console and create a Product, the images actually save.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    attr_accessible :description, :name, :category_ids, :brand_ids, :image_ids, :images_attributes

    has_many :images, :as => :imageable

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
    attr_accessible :name, :file
    mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
end

= simple_form_for(@product, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    .form-inputs
        = f.input :name
        = f.input :description

        = f.association :categories, as: :check_boxes
        = f.association :brands, as: :check_boxes

        = f.association :images

        = simple_fields_for :images do |i|
            = i.input :file, as: :file
            = i.input :name

    .form-actions
        = f.button :submit


# GET /products/new
# GET /products/new.json
def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.images.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
end

{
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"vvXZFh9sJivA3i4Y0rx9i/oqLwKByrExgYisfdj/N78=",
    "product"=> {
        "name"=>"sxsad",
        "description"=>"saasd",
        "category_ids"=>[""],
        "brand_ids"=>[""],
        "image_ids"=>[""]
     },

     # should be images_attributes and come straight after image_ids?
    "images"=>{
        "name"=>"sdfsdfsdf"
     },

    "commit"=>"Create Product"
}
```

Once i've got it working for one image I will look into something like Cocoon for multiple images. Any thoughts on where this could be going wrong would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply write:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :images do |i|
```

Comment: Ouch. That was one dumb typo. Thanks heaps, works as expected now!